# Regularization of a (divergent) cosine series

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

What would be a suitable regularized value for the following divergent series:

$$
S(y) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \cos(k y) \quad y \in R\\
$$

By way of added context, this series arises from a formal Fourier expansion. The regularized $S(y)$ is to be integrated subsequently over a symmetric, real interval.

Thanks.

Comment: [Related, though I'm not sure I'd call it a duplicate.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/822218/odd-mathematica-series-result)

Comment: @DanielFischer I up-voted your other answer.

Comment: As distribution sense on $\Bbb{T} = \Bbb{R}/2\pi\Bbb{Z}$, I guess the answer is $\frac{1}{2}( -1 + \delta_0)$.

Comment: [Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Fourier_kernels) to get $\pi\delta(x)-\frac 12$ (a slight modification of Sangchul Lee's comment concerning distribution theory).

Comment: Unless $y=0$, the answer does not depend on $y$ and is equal to $-1/2$